# Python Script not working on versioned Feature Class

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning, feature-dataset

I have a geoprocessing script that worked great, until moving the data source to a feature dataset where it must be versioned.

when this script is pointing to the layer outside the feature dataset, it runs fine.  When I point to the layer inside the feature dataset, the script still runs...no errors, but no updates are saved.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Sample code below:

```py
import arcpy, os

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1

#Set workspace and input fc variables
folderPath = r"S:\Data\Fires\Fire_Mapping_Analysis"
arcpy.env.workspace = folderPath + "\EmerOps as GIS.sde\EmerOps.GIS.FireBoundaries"
scratch_workspace = r"S:\Data\Fires\Fire_Mapping_Analysis\Fire_Map_Reports_Review.gdb"
BrushFire_fc = "\EmerOps.GIS.BrushFireAnalysis"


#Geoprocessing - Calculate fire acreage, perimeter, and class
try:
    print ("Calculating Fire acreage, perimeter, and class...")
    coords = "PROJCS['NAD_1983_StatePlane_California_V_FIPS_0405_Feet',GEOGCS['GCS_North_American_1983',DATUM['D_North_American_1983',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Lambert_Conformal_Conic'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',6561666.666666666],PARAMETER['False_Northing',1640416.666666667],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',-118.0],PARAMETER['Standard_Parallel_1',34.03333333333333],PARAMETER['Standard_Parallel_2',35.46666666666667],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',33.5],UNIT['Foot_US',0.3048006096012192]]"
    arcpy.management.CalculateGeometryAttributes(BrushFire_fc, "GIS_ACRES AREA;PERIMETER PERIMETER_LENGTH", "MILES_US", "ACRES", coords, "SAME_AS_INPUT")

    #Fire Classes by acreage

fields = ['GIS_ACRES', 'CLASS']

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor (BrushFire_fc, fields) as cursor:

    for row1 in cursor:
            if (row1[0] > 4999.5):
                row1[1] = "G"
                cursor.updateRow(row1)
            elif (row1[0] > 999.5 and row1[0] < 4999.4):
                row1[1] = "F"
                cursor.updateRow(row1)
            elif (row1[0] > 299.5 and row1[0] < 999.4):
                row1[1] = "E"
                cursor.updateRow(row1)
            elif (row1[0] > 99.95 and row1[0] < 299.4):
                row1[1] = "D"
                cursor.updateRow(row1)
            elif (row1[0] > 9.95 and row1[0] < 99.94):
                row1[1] = "C"
                cursor.updateRow(row1)
            elif (row1[0] > 0.255 and row1[0] < 9.94):
                row1[1] = "B"
                cursor.updateRow(row1)
            elif (row1[0] <= 0.254):
                row1[1] = "A"
                cursor.updateRow(row1)
                
            else:
                print("No records found")
            

except Exception as e:
    print ("Error: " + e.args[0])
```

The layer is versioned.  I think this is playing a big role here too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key was using arcpy.da.Editor.  The script would run, but the edits would not save without the Editor.  This seems to be the key when working with versioned datasets.

```
#Start edit session on versioned dataset
edit = arcpy.da.Editor(workspace, exclude feature dataset from path)
edit.startEditing(False, True)
edit.startOperation()

#geoprocessing during the edit session then...

#Stop editing and save edits
edit.stopOperation()
edit.stopEditing(True)
```